# Wasn't logged in when came from SO

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

I was logged in SO and there were some new notifications in my inbox so I clicked one that led me here but I was not logged in. Never happened before.

Using chrome 21.0.1180.57 on OSX

Comment: This has always been a bit finicky, tbh I'm not sure it's worth worrying about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce that behaviour.

You can visit the [Network Login Troubleshooting](https://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help) to check for the availability of certain necessary features in your browser in order to have the [network wide auto-login](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) functioning properly.

---

*[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98956/184576) may also apply to your issue.*

Comment: Well, it always (except once) worked so far. Using ff and chrome. I think it didn't work in ff.